# Zooming in to magnify Inset Map in Layout of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, zoom

[image]
this is the inset map I created in my layout view, notice how it is magnified to the full extent that I want to represent in my map

[image]

this is my map in its layout view with the inset map representation.

How can I zoom in on the inset map so it is magnified more just like in my data view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are in Layout View, go to the Table of Contents and right-click on the data frame to choose Activate.

Now you can use the Zoom/Pan tools on the Tools (not Layout) toolbar to alter the center and scale of your active data frame (which is now the Inset Map).  If it is already centered then just changing the Scale value would work too.